# How to retrieve constants for AngularJS from backend

Tags: angularjs

i have some application settings that i want to retrieve from backend, so that they would be available to all of my application controllers via injection. What is the most angular-way to do that?

1) If i only needed settings for one or few controllers i could retrieve them via routing resolve method, but what about global application scope?
2) I could use the .run() method, but since call will be async i have no guaranties that my config will be loaded before i access controllers.

Currently my settings are returned as a json object, and my templates/html files are simply served by web server. So i cannot embed anything into script tags, parse html on the server side or any similar technique.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a service for your settings. Then using the [.run()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#methods_run) method, called a service that returns your app settings data:

```
angular
.module('YourApp',[])
.service('Settings',function(){
    this.data = {}
})
.run(function(Settings,$http){
    $http
    .get('/ajax/app/settings')
    .success(function(data){
        Settings.data = data
    })
})

function Controller($scope,Settings){
    // use your Settings.data
}
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#methods_run

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat plugin to do the job. https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap

You need to change bootstrap method

```
deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
  element: document.body,
  module: 'MyApp',
  resolve: {
    APP_CONFIG: function ($http) {
      return $http.get('/api/demo-config');
    }
  }
});
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(function (APP_CONFIG) {
    console.log(APP_CONFIG);
  });
```