# AngularJS $http return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS` and only aware of the basics of AngularJS. I want to return a value from  `$http`. That is `$http` should return a value to the global variable of My Application.

I have tried this:

```
var sessionValues = null;
var AdminController = angular.module('AdminController', []);

AdminController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http','$location',
function ($scope, $http, $location){
$http({
        method: "post",
        url: "API/MyPage.php",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data){
        sessionValues = eval(data);
        console.log(sessionValues); /*Returns desired string*/
    }).error(function(){
        $scope.message="Some error has occured";
    });
    console.log(sessionValues); /*Returns null */
  }
]);
```

I tried using `$rootScope`, but was not successful.

I understand that this is because it is an asynchronous call, but how can I fetch the value in JS's global variable.?

Can anyone help me about this.?

Comment: Have you tried $scope.sessionValues?

Comment: @Blunderfest: Yes, I tried that too. But not working.

Comment: @Veer: But...you **are** storing the value in JS's global variable. What is the problem ???

Comment: @ExpertSystem: something is wrong with async calls. The value is not delivered to the JS global variable

Comment: @Veer: Nothing is wrong. You probably have some reading to do on async execution :) The asyncronicity of the `$http` call means that the global JS variable will be updated at a later time. You just happen to try to access it sooner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is indeed with the async nature of call and when you are trying to access the variable. `console.log` returns null because it gets called before the `$http` call is complete.

Firstly we do not pollute the JavaScript global scope, but use services\factory, $rootScope to access data.

In you case if you want to expose a variable to across angular, the easiest way is to use $rootScope. Something like this

```
AdminController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$http','$location','$rootScope'
  function ($scope, $http, $location,$rootScope){
  $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "API/MyPage.php",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data){
        $rootScope.sessionValues = eval(data);
        console.log($rootScope.sessionValues); /*Returns desired string*/
    }).error(function(){
        $scope.message="Some error has occured";
    });
    console.log($rootScope.sessionValues); /*Returns will always null due to async nature call*/
  }
]);
```

You then have to access that variable only after it has been filled in the success call back, before that it would be always null. The `console.log` would always fail.

To know when the variable value has changed you can use AngularJS watch http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Comment: Rootscope is not at all required when the conversation involves only one level of scope. Factoriy method is the appropriate choice

Comment: Scoping of services\factories and rootscope is similar. if the data is required in a single scope actually neither rootscope nor services\factory is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to retrieve a constant from backend service before application loaded.

You can refer to [How to retrieve constants for AngularJS from backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821018/how-to-retrieve-constants-for-angularjs-from-backend/23584075#23584075)

In your controller, you can get the APP_CONFIG directly.

```
AdminController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http','$location','APP_CONFIG'
function ($scope, $http, $location, APP_CONFIG){
});
```

You can reuse APP_CONFIG at any angular controller, service or factory.